# storyboard and uitableview dilemma

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

Ok, so I have a UITableViewController. In it I have dynamic tableviewcell defined. For now to make things simple lets say there are three dynamic rows defined. see screenshot

[image]

So what I am want to do is that when user touches

- row 1, I want to take them to viewcontroller1
- row 2, I want to take them to viewcontroller2
- row 3, I want to take them to viewcontroller3

Now here's the dilemma part, when I select the prototype cell and connect it to viewcontroller1 using modal then from then onwards any row I touch it will always take me to viewcontroller1. I thought of writing this code for my  UITableViewController but I don't know how to create multiple sages? (see below)

Now it may very well be that this is a limitation of storyboard and UITableView and it cannot be done using dynamic cell. What I will have to do is create static cells and manually connect each of the rows to the corresponding view controller. I just wanted to know if there is an easier way as I got 50 rows and each row needs to be connected to a new view controller. Yes I  love connecting stuff in storyboard that much. Just wanted to get a second opinion if there are any better approaches.

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.

        //SECTION #0
        if (indexPath.section == 0)
        {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goto1" sender:nil];

        }

    //SECTION #1
        if (indexPath.section == 1)
        {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goto2" sender:nil];

        }

    //SECTION #2
        if (indexPath.section == 2)
        {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goto3" sender:nil];

        }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's also possible to drag a segue from the yellow controller icon in the controller toolbar. Select your table view controller and a black toolbar like pictured below will show up.

[image: Controller Toolbar]

Drag from the yellow icon to the desired destination controller.

This way a segue is not directly attached to a cell or anything else. Give it an identifier and you can perform it in code whenever you want.

In your case you call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` based on whatever logic you seem fit.

**[edit]:**

> "Just wanted to get a second opinion if there are any better approaches."

50 different segues & destinations seems an awful lot. Are you sure you're not able to reuse a single (or at least less than 50) view controller(s) (say when only the content differs?). For example you display 50 similar pages with content. Instead of creating 50 view controllers in your storyboard: create a single one and set the content of the view controller before it is shown:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    MyPageController *page = (MyPageController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    // get content for selected row
    page.content = myContentModelObject;
}
```

Comment: holy molly, i didn't realize I could multi connect sages this way. Oh thank you so much for this perfect answer!

Comment: @SamBudda - This will still mean you're going to be dragging 50 segue lines out... and labelling them all... i don't imagine you want to do that.

Comment: ah, was also editing at the same time. Are you sure you actually need 50 segues?

Comment: trust me the choice I had was to create 50 segues and rearrange my custom UIImageViews in each of the view controller in story board ... or to write hundreds of lines of code to manually adjust the location and size of my UIImageViews in one view controller.m file. I have done the code side of things in the past and its just awfully painful. Yeah it seems like a lot of connect but once I am done ... I am done and I know it won't take me more than 30 mins to do

Comment: I just hope there is not some sort of Xcode limitation that it will start crashing because of number of view controller I have dragged and dropped in there

Answer (score 0):

Segues can only be created by dragging lines out in the Storyboard. Once they are created, you can customise them but that's not much use if you have to draw them all in the first place.

To save you drawing all those lines (and debugging them...) you can easily do the work of a Segue without using the storyboard. For a modal segue:

```
#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString* identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
    RWViewController* detailView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];
    [self presentViewController:detailView animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

You can still create your 50 ViewControllers in the storyboard. Give each one a numerical identifier that matches to the corresponding indexpath.row

No lines to draw...

If the storyboard becomes overwhelming at 50 viewControllers, consider using a separate xib for each one (or you could break out a few different stoyboards, and arrange them in groups).